# htaccess file redirect everything except

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying to redirect all pages to the homepage except the ones who are in a specific url. So for clarification redirect all pages to the root expect www.ourwebsite.com/mydir/link1
All the pages in mydir should show up but if someone goes to mydir/ they should redirect to home.

I'm using wordpress so there is a .htaccess file:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ / [R=301,L] // Redirects all to homepage
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

So this should redirect all pages to homepage but now when someone types /mydir/link1 or /mydir/link2 etc they shouldn't be redirected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a condition for exceptions:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/(dist/|mydir/(link1|link2)) [NC]
RewriteRule . / [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Remember to clear your browser cache before testing this redirect rule.

Comment: Should I just change the rewriterule to what I previously had?

Comment: Yes just add `RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST}` before your existing rule #1

Comment: I changed the RewriteRule to ^(.*)$ this still end up with err_too_many_redirects

Comment: What is exact URL you entered in browser? Did you clear your browser cache completely?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104304/discussion-between-michiel-and-anubhava).